# K-fold cross validation to reduce overfitting : problem with the implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, error-handling, cross-validation, k-fold

It is the first time I am trying to use cross-validation and I am facing an error.

Firstly my dataset looks like this :

[image]

So, in order to avoid/reduce the overfitting of my model I am trying to use a k-fold cross validation.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
X,y = creation_X_y() #Function which is cleaning my data
kf = KFold(n_splits=5) 

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index)
    X_train = X[train_index]
    X_test = X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

However, I am facing the following error and I am not finding how I could solve it. I am understanding that it looks for these values in the columns but it should probably look in the index no ? May I use X.loc[train_index] for example ?

Thanks in advance for your time and your help !

[image]

Comment: You can use stratify split or do you want only to use KFold?

Comment: I found about stratify k-fold which was great for imbalanced dataset (which is my case) so I am going to try it too

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct: `.iloc[index]` will work.
Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
X,y = creation_X_y() #Function which is cleaning my data
kf = KFold(n_splits=5) 

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index)
    X_train = X.iloc[train_index]
    X_test = X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

Another way is to make `creation_X_y()` return a `numpy.array`.